# Black Screen after login, gnome shell overwriting existing binding

Tags: gnome-shell, 20.10, gnome-shell-extension, shortcut-keys

I just installed Ubuntu 20.10 after a long time with Arch, and it everything was going well.

Then I used the key combination I set (alt+space) to switch input methods from English to German. The desktop froze, and upon reboot & login I am greeted with a cursor on a black background.

journalctl -b 0 is completely filled with

```
gnome-shell: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 71 with keysym 40 (keycode 18).
```

After a new attempt at starting gnome-shell 71 and 40 may be exchanged.

I don’t know what this is all about, but I found many posts that had black screens and similar messages. For instance [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306001/ubuntu-20-04gnome-black-screen-after-login-for-some-user). Sadly no solutions. I tried uninstalling gnome-shell-extension-Ubuntu-dock, but no luck.

When setting up Ubuntu I did change quite a few shortcuts in order to set up the different language inputs, and to deactivate the incredibly annoying Super+number launch from the dock (why is the setting for this buried so deep??). Keycode 18 is the alt key. I don’t know what keysym 40 and 71 are.

**edit**

I purged the nvidia drivers, and now the above mentioned message appears only a few times in journalctf -b. However, gnome-shell still fails to start.

```
Starting gnome shell on x11...
...
org.gnome.shell@x11.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
```

I purged and reinstalled ubuntu-desktop, gnome-shell etc, but the problem persists.

i3wm starts just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by fcitx. It and gnome-shell were apparently switching things back and forth, causing the freeze. I uninstalled fcitx and am using ibus now.

Answer (score 0):

Great job! gnome not only conflicts with fcitx but also with some other video features such like chrome and other nvidia-support appications.