# Screen blacks out for 2 seconds and shifts/flickers several times a day

Tags: google-chrome, lenovo, screen, amd-processor

As the title suggest, this screen issue has appeared 6-8ish weeks ago and I bought the laptop a year ago, never had an issue before.

The issue seems to happen when I watch videos on YT using Chrome and only with Ubuntu because I tried putting back the original SSD that came with the laptop that has Windows 11 on and there's no screen issue using Windows.

The issue mostly only happens on the laptop screen, but rarely will also black out my external monitor, though I have no clue if it's related.

Laptop specs:
Thinkpad T14s Gen 3
Processor: AMD Ryzen™ 7 PRO 6850U
Graphic Card Integrated AMD Radeon™ Graphics
Memory 32 GB LPDDR5-6400MHz
Display: 14" WUXGA (1920 x 1200), IPS, Anti-Glare, Non-Touch, 72%NTSC, 400 nits, Narrow Bezel, Low Power
OS: Ubuntu 23.04

Edit 8 nov:

Doing `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` right after it happens a few times I see this log repeated a bunch of times:

```
gnome-shell[2817]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
```

It seems somtehing similar happenned to other people but I'm not sure what toi make of it:
[Black Screen after login, gnome shell overwriting existing binding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325453/black-screen-after-login-gnome-shell-overwriting-existing-binding)

Any idea how to troubleshoot the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Just after it happens, the terminal command `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` will show any logged activity. Otherwise, suspect power/overheating/hardware

Comment: So I've been running the laptop with the Windows SSD for a few weeks and I didn't get a blank screen once. Just put my Ubuntu SSD back in and it still happens every few minutes or so, so I highly doubt it's a hardware issue. I added the journalctl command and result to my original post because of character limit in the comments.

Comment: [Edit] your Question to add new information.

Comment: I did but I just added Edit 8 nov to it to make it more obvious.

Comment: I got too fed up to troubleshoot I reinstalled a new Ubuntu 23.10 on the laptop and it seemed fine for a couple days and the same thing started to happen again. To say that I'm over it would be an understatement!